# Access- Open form with where clause

Tags: ms-access, combobox, where-clause

I need to open a specific form by a click on a subform record name. The name in the subform is showed as a combobox with ID and Name as columns.

I did like this:

```
Private Sub ID_Prodotto_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
Dim Id As Integer
Id = Me.ID_Prodotto.Column.Value
DoCmd.OpenForm "Prodotto", , , "ID_Prodotto = " & Id
End Sub
```

But Access requires me to manually insert the ID Field Value as I click on the record. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Can't replicate your error with this information. Is the form based off a  query requiring the ID as a parameter? Try to make your question [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try simply Me.ID_Prodotto . Add a debug.print ID to see what value it is being set to. Is ID_Prodotto on the form you are opening ?

Comment: The form I want to open is wizard-generated by access as a form referring to a table and resuming data record by record. In the table there is of course the ID_Prodotto parameter and also in the form. In fact if I write a value manually when access asks me to do so, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should read:

```
Id = Me!ID_Prodotto.Value
```

or, if you wish to use the value from column number n (0 is the first):

```
Id = Me!ID_Prodotto.Column(n)
```

Comment: Then you probably don't have an ID_Prodotto control or field.