# Open form using macro with where clause and it opens dialog box

Tags: ms-access, vba, openform

I have an issue with "where condition" in macro on OpenForm in Access 2016.

I'm struggling with exactly the same issue, meaning a dialog window opening in between forms as in the link below:

[Access- Open form with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588915/access-open-form-with-where-clause)

I have a condition like this in macro builder on OpenForm:

```
="ID_code_SC = " & [Forms]![SearchFRM_Materiel]![ID_code_SC]
```

and it still asks me to type the name of the ID. If I type it, it goes to a correct record.

Importantly, my ID is a text, such as ABC_01. So I modified it according to:
http://www.baldyweb.com/wherecondition.htm

and I have:

```
="ID_code_SC = '" & [Forms]![SearchFRM_Materiel]![ID_code_SC] & "'"
```

but this, on the other hand, opens an empty form and doesn't refer to any record.

I use Access 2016. I'm very new to Access and macros/VBA, so most likely I don't see some basic mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
"ID_code_SC = '" & [Forms]![SearchFRM_Materiel]![ID_code_SC] & "'"
```

Comment: Nope. Then in the dialog I have something like this: Forms!SearchFRM_Materiel!ID_code_SC instead of the ID.

Comment: That indicates, that form `SearchFRM_Materiel` isn't open.